# Grep -f seems to return every file in a directory

Tags: linux, grep

I am using grep -f to search through a directory for files that match the strings in the file I provide. Below is the command I am using

```
$find $(pwd) -type f |grep -f list.txt >result.txt
```

I am using the $pwd and find to display the complete path of the file when it is written to result.txt

When I run this command, I seem to return every file in the working directory and below.

List.txt contains (this is the "input"):

```
AAA_ERROR_2023_02_21.zip
ABA_ERROR_2023_02_23.zip
ACA_ERROR_2023_02_21.zip
AAA_LOG_2023_02_21.zip
```

Input is from an Excel list I copied and pasted from (I confirmed the files are there with a simple grep for the file name). Input in this sense is what is inside of list.txt

Output:

```
//returns almost everything in the sub directories
```

Expected output:

```
sampledirectory/parent/02/21/testfile_example_AAA_ERROR_2023_02_21.zip
sampledirectory/parent/02/23/testfile_example_ABA_ERROR_2023_02_23.zip
sampledirectory/parent/02/21/testfile_example_ACA_ERROR_2023_02_21.zip
sampledirectory/parent/02/21/testfile_example_AAA_LOG_2023_02_21.zip
```

I have tried |fgrep -wf list.txt and other variations with -o as well,

Is it possible the "_" in the file are messing up the pattern? Or is it possible my search list is not specific enough?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: (1) What is `-find`? Is it `find`? (2) What is "input"? Is it the content of `list.txt`? Being explicit is a virtue. (3) Is there an empty line in `list.txt` maybe?

Comment: 1)Sorry about that. The exact command is $find $(pwd) -type f |grep -f list.txt >result.txt. 2)Input is from an excel list I copied and pasted from (I confirmed the files are there with a simple grep for the file name). Input in this sense is what is inside of list.txt

Comment: (3, alternative): What is the output of `grep -c '^$' list.txt`?

Comment: It returned the exact number of lines in the file. I think I solved the issue, I ended up remaking the list.txt and taking off the last character in each string. This seemed to fix the whole issue. My hypothesis is Excel must have been adding some special character at the end that was throwing the grep off. Thank you for your replies Kamil

Comment: If the lines terminated by carriage-return+line-feed, this might have created blank lines (zero-length strings) that grep happily found in every file. Hilarious.

Comment: Welcome to SU, and great to have the issue resolved :-) As you've resolved the issue, the next step would be [writing an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer), and drop back later to accept it. Help-section has good [advice on how to formulate it](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). That'll ensure this won't pop up in the future as "Unanswered", and will make it helpful for others facing similar issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how *exactly* did you transfer the information from Excel (on Windows?) to Linux (the question is tagged `linux`)?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was caused by zero length strings added by Microsoft. Be careful when making your text files that grep will use.

As per harrymc " the lines terminated by carriage-return+line-feed, this might have created blank lines (zero-length strings) that grep happily found in every file..."

Comment: You could enhance your answer by quoting a reference. Then it would becworthy of upvotes.

Comment: Helpful. This was my first Stack post so I wasn't aware of the etiquette

Comment: Nobody is at first :-) Q&A sites like SE are quite different from discussion forums. Taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) are a good way of finding out how things work. And, of course, checking out questions with accepted answer.